# counting non-unique rows in table with additional criteria

Tags: sql, mysql, count

I have a table USERS with the following fields

date(datetime)
email(varchar)
provider(int)
event(int)

I am looking for how many records there are with the same email, which occur in a specific month with a specific provider.

like for provider= x and month = y i want

```
email              occurs
peter@peter.com    5
peter@peter.co.uk  2
```

I know it should be WHERE provider= x and MONTH(date) = y, but how can i get how a count of all the emails out of the table? is it possible?

sorry if this isnt very clear! thanks for your help

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This should work:

```
SELECT email, COUNT(*) AS occurs
WHERE provider = x AND YEARMONTH(date) = y
GROUP BY email
HAVING occurs > 1
```